# New to solidity. Help: UnimplementedFeatureError: Copying of type struct TransactionContract.Product memory[] memory to storage not yet supported

Tags: solidity, struct

I have here a solidity program that I am trying to make, it should store the transaction to the blockchain, this transaction contains, id, date, buyer, seller, ORnumber, a multiple products with their corresponding prices, and a total of those prices. I tried creating two structs and the other struct will contain the Products with their prices. This is my code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract TransactionContract {
    struct Product {
        string name;
        uint256 price;
    }

struct Transaction {
    uint256 id;
    uint256 date;
    address buyer;
    address seller;
    uint256 ORnumber;
    Product[] products;
    uint256 total;
}

Transaction[] public transactions;

function addTransaction(
    uint256 _id,
    uint256 _date,
    address _buyer,
    address _seller,
    uint256 _ORnumber,
    Product[] memory _products
) public {
    uint256 _total = 0;
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < _products.length; i++) {
        _total += _products[i].price;
    }

    Transaction memory newTransaction = Transaction({
        id: _id,
        date: _date,
        buyer: _buyer,
        seller: _seller,
        ORnumber: _ORnumber,
        products: _products,
        total: _total
    });

    transactions.push(newTransaction);
}

function getTransaction(uint256 _index)
    public
    view
    returns (
        uint256 id,
        uint256 date,
        address buyer,
        address seller,
        uint256 ORnumber,
        Product[] memory products,
        uint256 total
    )
{
    require(_index < transactions.length, "Transaction index out of bounds.");
    Transaction storage transaction = transactions[_index];

    return (
        transaction.id,
        transaction.date,
        transaction.buyer,
        transaction.seller,
        transaction.ORnumber,
        transaction.products,
        transaction.total
    );
}

function getAllTransactions()
    public
    view
    returns (Transaction[] memory)
{
    return transactions;
}
}
```

But an error is keeping me from compiling it.

UnimplementedFeatureError: Copying of type struct TransactionContract.Product memory[] memory to storage not yet supported.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

The error is becaused you're trying to directly assign a dynamic array of structs (_products) from `memory` to `storage`.

```
products: _products,
```

Solidity doesn't support this operation.

I've modified the `addTransaction` function to fix it.

The main changes are:

- Directly assign values to the struct in storage, avoiding the copying
  error.
- Loop through the `_products` array and push each product into
  the storage array individually.

These changes should resolve the error and make your function work as expected.

```
function addTransaction(
    uint256 _id,
    uint256 _date,
    address _buyer,
    address _seller,
    uint256 _ORnumber,
    Product[] memory _products
) public   {
    
    uint256 _total = 0;
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < _products.length; i++) {
        _total += _products[i].price;
    }

    uint256 transactionIndex = transactions.length;

    // Assign values to the Transaction struct in storage
    Transaction storage newTransaction = transactions[transactionIndex];
    newTransaction.id = _id;
    newTransaction.date = _date;
    newTransaction.buyer = _buyer;
    newTransaction.seller = _seller;
    newTransaction.ORnumber = _ORnumber;
    newTransaction.total = _total;

    for (uint256 i = 0; i < _products.length; i++) {
        newTransaction.products.push(_products[i]);
    }
}
```